# To match any number greater than 15 using regexp

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I tried to match any number greater than 15 using the following regexp:

```
0*[1-9][6-9][0-9]*
```

But I can match only 2 digit number eg. I can unmatch successfully `12` or `13` (less than `15`) , whereas I am unable to match `105`, `124` etc..

Anyone help me out how to resolve this.

Comment: 0*[1-9]([6-9]|[0-9][0-9])[0-9]*

Comment: `^[1-9]{3,}|1[6-9]|[2-9][0-9]$` work fine

Comment: Thanks paj28, it solved my issue

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1171/

Comment: Exactly @cmbuckley why using regex when conversion to int + comparison will keep a code maintenable and readable

Comment: You could try it with lookaheads `^(?!0*(\d|1[0-5])$)\d+$`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/iDJVLv/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any number greater than 15 is

- Any number with 3 or more digits with possible leading 0's
- Any number with 2 digits where the first digit in in the character class [2-9]
- Any number with 2 digits where the first digit is 1 and the second digit in in the character class [6-9]

From these three rules we can build the regex, assumes that what we are matching only contains digits

```
/^0*(?:[1-9][0-9]{2,}|[2-9][0-9]|1[6-9])$/
```

If you can't use an extended regex then the following should work

```
/^0*[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*|0*[2-9][0-9]|0*1[6-9]$/
```

Comment: This assumes extended regular expressions, i.e.`-r` option with `sed` or `-E` option with `grep`

Comment: This should work fine `^[1-9]{3,}|1[6-9]|[2-9][0-9]$`

Comment: This won't match 100

Comment: Add `0*` at the begining to match any leading 0

Comment: 0100 won't match

Comment: Dam numbers are hard :-)

Comment: Well, regex are maybe not suited for that purpose :)